# Unwanted data binding in vue js

Tags: data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a edit form in my application. When this component is created http request is sent and response data is saved in two different variables.

```
axios.get(this.initializeURL)
    .then((res) => {
        this.form = res.data.form
        this.formInit = res.data.form
    })
```

and "this.form" is binded with form inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" v-model="form.name">
```

My problem is : When the input fields are changed "this.formInit" object is also changed. but i haven't bind "this.formInit" with input fields.

Isn't the "this.formInit" supposed to contain the initial data from the response ?

Why is this unwanted binding happening ?

My goal is to compare "this.form" & "this.formInit" to check if the user changes some fields before tring to update the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new object using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
axios.get(this.initializeURL)
    .then((res) => {
        this.form = Object.assign({}, res.data.form),
        this.formInit = res.data.form
    })
```